# Add 2 points on google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been working on this for a few days now and still cannot seem to quite get it.
I need two pins to display on the map. Any advice would be great.
Here is what I have so far:

```js
   $.martanianGoogleMapInit = function() {

var lat = 36.777259; 
var lng = -76.036311;var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );



        var mapOptions = {
        
            zoom: 1,
            center: map_center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
      
        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'google-map' ), mapOptions );
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
            map: map
        });
    };
```

Comment: are you calling `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback= martanianGoogleMapInit"
        async defer></script>` ? at the end of the page?

Comment: Your code is showing me the marker, which is exactly the issue you're having? If the map is not showing at all may be because you're missing the call @morels said or you're missing to enable the Google Maps Javascript API

Comment: How are you trying to add the second marker?

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to work for me using my own API key. I get two markers.
You could choose to create a function that takes an input of array with multiple lat+lng values and iterate the "new google.maps.Marker()" function.

Ofcourse, as others have pointed out in the comments, you must have a reference to the Google Maps API in your , provided with your own API KEY.

```
$.martanianGoogleMapInit = function() {
    var lat = 36.777259; 
    var lng = -76.036311;
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: map_center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'google-map' ), mapOptions );
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
            map: map
        });

        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat+0.0101, lng ),
            map: map
        });
    };
```